# Where is this lake?

Tags: identify-this, norway, mountains, lakes

The filename of this image is "rocky mountains", but it rather looks like Norway to me.  Where is it exactly?  No source I find through Google Images or through tineye will be more specific than „rocky mountains”.

[image: Rocky mountains?]
http://travelerguidance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/rocky-mountains.jpg

Comment: I was going to suggest that perhaps the site was referring simply to "mountains that are rocky" instead of the Rocky Mountains, but in fact [the article that includes this picture](http://travelerguidance.com/rocky-mountains-2/) refers specifically to the Rocky Mountains in Colorado. Seems disingenuous.

Comment: @GregHewgill Right.  I forgot to mention that I actually found this picture when I searched google images for Colorado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's taken in [Hamnøy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamn%C3%B8y), in the Lofoten island in Norway.

You can even make out the specific mountain shown in your photo in the image included on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Right.  I thought it looked like northern Norway.

Comment: Hamnøy is actually behind the photographer. The image must have been taken from the bridge between Hamnøya and Toppøya. The highest peak is called "Olstinden".

Answer (score 5):

To answer the *precise* question, the lake is called "The Norwegian Sea".

I wish I could say "And I've climbed that". I've done some peaks around Reine (the larger settlement on the west side of the fjord, Hamnøy being the old ferry quay before they built the bridge, and BTW on the right of the photographer, we are looking slightly east of north and behind him/her is only the Lofotfjord), but none of those in the picture. And now I never will, boo hoo.

Comment: Right, I asked *lake* in my question because it was claimed to be in Colorado...